# intersection of equivalence relations

Tags: set-theory, equivalence-relations

There's a question I dont understand.

> If R and S are equivalence relations on a set , then which of the following is guaranteed to be an equivalence relation again:
>
> - R ∪ S
> - R ∩ S
> - R * S
> - R / S

The answer given is **R ∩ S**, but to my understanding I thought it was impossible to intersect two equivalent sets. So I assume that the only possible answers are all but **R ∩ S**

Comment: What do you mean that it's impossible to intersect two equivalent sets? $R$ and $S$ definitely don't have to be the same set, if that's what you mean by their equivalence.

Comment: You may be confusing equivalence classes and equivalence relations. $R$ and $S$ are  relations, sets of ordered pairs. If they’re equivalence relations on the same set $X$, then both contain the diagonal $\{(x, x) \,|\, x \in X\}$, so their intersection can’t be empty (unless $X$ is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question does not ask about intersecting **equivalence sets**, it asks about intersecting the **equivalent relations** themselves. For example on the set $A:= \{ 1,2,3,4\}$ I can define the equivalence relation $R$ on $A$ to mean that $x,y \in A$ are equivalent iff $x$ and $y$ have the same parity (in the sense of either both being even or both being odd. The **equivalence sets** you talk about are $\{1,3 \}$ and $\{2,4\}$ in my example, since those are the sets of numbers having the same parity. However the **equivalence relation** $R$ is the set of all tuples over $A$ satisfying the condition. So we get $R = \{(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4),(1,3),(3,1),(2,4),(4,2) \}$.

The question talks about intersecting two such sets $R$ and $S$, and it is straightforward checking that $R \cap S$ satisfies the definition of an equivalence relation.

Comment: I understand now, THANKS

Comment: I have defined only one equivalence relation $R$. Feel free to define a second equivalence relation $S$ on $A$ and see what happens when intersecting them. My answer was mainly there to clear up your confusion between the equivalence relation and an equivalence set.